# apply position of points to other object

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a path (curve) and added a point on each endpoint. I would like to generate a cube and have the x value of it's vertices to be places at the x value of the endpoints. I tried to do something like that but the indices and the dimensions are off.. It doesn't start at the exact startpoint of the curve.. Can anyone help?
I would like to make the sideboards of basic stairs.
[image]
[image]
[image: The nodes I have now to generate the deformed cube]
[image: This is the curve with the points]